# Filter flatten master-slave

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that is badly designed to be saved as a "master-slave" relation based on order, like:

```
{
    _id: 1
    type: 'master',
    color: 'Blue'
},
{
    _id: 2
    type: 'slave',
    color: 'Blue'
},
{
    _id: 3
    type: 'slave',
    color: 'Green'
},
{
    _id: 4
    type: 'master',
    color: 'red'
},
{
    _id: 5
    type: 'slave',
    color: 'Blue'
}
```

What I need to do now is filter this collection in a way that if a master document is filtered out, all of its "slaves" should also be. For example, if I filter by the color `Blue` I want to get the following documents:

```
{
    _id: 1
    type: 'master',
    color: 'Blue'
},
{
    _id: 2
    type: 'slave',
    color: 'Blue'
}
```

Notice that the document with `id: 5` should be filtered out because its "master" is not `Blue`.

How can I achieve this with good performance?

**Disclaimer: I do understand that this is a bad design and the "slaves" probably should be nested into the "masters", but unfortunely is not an option to change this design right now :/**